# JS / d3.js: Creating groups for source/target links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to colour some nodes based on their links but I am not sure how to do so. Here is my current graph:

[image: My current Graph]

I have been trying to automatically colour all nodes that are within the same cluster (i.e. Connected to each other either by being a source or a target to any node within the cluster), but so far all my attempts have been futile..

I heard that I might need to do a recursive function, but my recursion is self-taught and is fundamentally wrong. Here is my current code:

```
function assignGroup() {
var groupedNodes = [];

for(var i = 0; i < gNodes.length; i++) {
    if(nodes[i].group !== undefined) {
        nodes[i].group = undefined;
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if(nodes[i].group === undefined) {
        nodes[i].group = i;
        recursive(nodes[i],i);
    }
}


function recursive(rNode, rGrp) {       
    var tempSrc = hasSrc(rNode);        
    var tempTarg = hasTarg(rNode);

    if(tempSrc == null && tempTarg == null)
        return;

    if(tempSrc != null && tempSrc.group === undefined) {
        tempSrc.group = rGrp;
        recursive(tempSrc, rGrp);
    }

    if(tempTarg != null && tempTarg.group === undefined) {
        tempTarg.group = rGrp;
        recursive(tempTarg, rGrp);
    }
}

function hasTarg(eNode) {
    for(var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        if(nodes.name == edges[i].source)
            return getNode(nodes, edges[i].target);
        else
            return null;
    }
}

function hasSrc(eNode) {
    for(var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        if (nodes.name == edges[i].target)
            return getNode(edges[i].source);
        else
            return null;
    }
}

function getNode(id) {
    console.log(id);
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if(id == nodes[i].name) {
            return nodes[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My approach is to assign a group to each node, and to colour them based on their group, essentially tackling two birds with one stone (Group can be used for future implementations as well).

My dataset is:

```
{
"nodes":
[
 {
   "name": "Ben",
},
 {
   "name": "May",
},
 {
   "name": "Jack",
},
 {
   "name": "Francis",
},
 {
   "name": "Owen",
},
 {
   "name": "Blake",
},
 {
   "name": "Julia",
},
 {
   "name": "Liam",
}
],
"edges":
[
    {
        "source":"Ben",
        "target":"May"
    },
    {
        "source":"Ben",
        "target":"Blake"
    },
    {
        "source":"Ben",
        "target":"Owen"
    },
    {
        "source":"Owen",
        "target":"Julia"
    }
]
}
```

Here is the intended outcome of my dataset for node:

```
"nodes":
[
 {
   "name": "Ben",
   "group": 1
},
 {
   "name": "May",
   "group": 1
},
 {
   "name": "Jack",
   "group": 2 /*Arbitrary group (Ungrouped)*/
},
 {
   "name": "Francis",
   "group": 3 /*Arbitrary group (Ungrouped)*/
},
 {
   "name": "Owen",
   "group": 1
},
 {
   "name": "Blake",
   "group": 1
},
 {
   "name": "Julia",
   "group": 1
},
 {
   "name": "Liam",
   "group": 4 /*Arbitrary group (Ungrouped)*/
}
]
```

Edit: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehnf76xg/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my solution. First, we give each node a different number:

```
data.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.group = i
});
```

The numbers themselves don't matter, as you know.

Then we check, for each node, if its name is found at the `source` or `target` of each object in the `edges` array. If yes, we give its number to both source and target correspondents in the `nodes` array:

```
data.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    data.edges.forEach(function(e) {
        if (e.source === d.name || e.target === d.name) {
            data.nodes.find(function(f) {
                return f.name === e.source
            }).group = d.group;
            data.nodes.find(function(f) {
                return f.name === e.target
            }).group = d.group;
        }
    })
})
```

This is just like an infectious process: the first node whose name is found either on `source` or `target` spreads its number. Again, the number itself doesn't matter.

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "Ben",
  }, {
    "name": "May",
  }, {
    "name": "Jack",
  }, {
    "name": "Francis",
  }, {
    "name": "Owen",
  }, {
    "name": "Blake",
  }, {
    "name": "Julia",
  }, {
    "name": "Liam",
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "May"
  }, {
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "Blake"
  }, {
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "Owen"
  }, {
    "source": "Owen",
    "target": "Julia"
  }]
};

data.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.group = i
});

data.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  data.edges.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.source === d.name || e.target === d.name) {
      data.nodes.find(function(f) {
        return f.name === e.source
      }).group = d.group;
      data.nodes.find(function(f) {
        return f.name === e.target
      }).group = d.group;
    }
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

Now, let's see it in a real force directed chart:

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "Ben",
  },{
    "name": "May",
  }, {
    "name": "Jack",
  }, {
    "name": "Liam",
  },{
    "name": "Francis",
  }, {
    "name": "Owen",
  }, {
    "name": "Blake",
  }, {
    "name": "Julia",
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "May"
  }, {
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "Blake"
  }, {
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "Owen"
  }, {
    "source": "Owen",
    "target": "Julia"
  }]
};

data.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.group = i
});

data.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  data.edges.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.source === d.name || e.target === d.name) {
      data.nodes.find(function(f) {
        return f.name === e.source
      }).group = d.group;
      data.nodes.find(function(f) {
        return f.name === e.target
      }).group = d.group;
    }
  })
})

var svg = d3.select("svg")

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink()
    .id(function(d) {
      return d.name
    }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(15))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(150, 70));

var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(data.edges)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#aaa")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("stroke", "#444")
  .style("stroke-width", 2)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  })


force.nodes(data.nodes);
force.force("link")
  .links(data.edges);

force.on("tick", function() {
  edges.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much yet again! :) Works perfectly! Too bad the max number of upvotes is 1.. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Just a small edit to your answer, while I ran the data with more node entries, i realised that the group number taken is from the one that is the most recent (i.e. the higher group number is taken) and as it is non-recursive, the group number is only changed for the source/target pair at the bottom (later in) of the array. 

Hence, I set the group number to:

(getGroup(e.source) < d.group)? getGroup(e.source):d.group;

To take the earlier group number instead, therefore allowing the change to 'propagate' to the later nodes. 

Thank you! :)

Comment: That's funny, the way I wrote the code it should be the *least* recent. Can you show me the data you're using, or a dummy data to reproduce that?

Comment: Sure :) Let me do it in a separate answer, i cant seem to write the whole code in comments

Comment: Don't do that: answers are for answers only. Just copy/paste it in a fiddle or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have created a jsFiddle and edited the qn, its below :)

Comment: Edit: Something weird happened, when I tried to re-create the scenario again the problem did not occur.. seems like it fixed itself over dinner.. my bad sorry for the false alarm. 

Previously, as the middle node "Kate" was the last node in the array, all the nodes around "Kate" changed their groups to match "Kate"'s group, which was group 22. This left out "Jackson", which was the node one-hop away from "Kate" and hence not changed (Left at 17). This was my observation before dinner though.

Comment: The code is running as it should be: the first person in the edge is `Beatrice`, which is group 9, meaning that the first repeating group is 9. EDIT: It seems that we posted the comments at the same time! Good to know that the problem "fixed itself"...

Comment: Yep its working now, sorry for the false alarm! Thank you for the help as well! Have a great day :)